# Why such a definiton for "exchangeable" event?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations, random-variables, definition

I quote **Mörters/Peres (2010)**

> **Definition** Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$ and consider a set $A$ of sequences such that
> \begin{equation}
> \left\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\in A\right\}\in\mathcal{F}
> \end{equation}
> The event $\left\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\in A\right\}$ is called exchangeable if
> \begin{equation}
> \left\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\in A\right\}\subset\left\{X_{\sigma_1}, X_{\sigma_2},\ldots\in A\right\}
> \end{equation}
> for all finite permutations $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$. Here finite permutation means that $\sigma$ is a bijection with $\sigma_n=n$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

---

---

What I cannot understand is why definition is:
\begin{equation}
\left\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\in A\right\}\color{red}{\subset}\left\{X_{\sigma_1}, X_{\sigma_2},\ldots\in A\right\}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
and not:
\begin{equation}
\left\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\in A\right\}\color{red}{=}\left\{X_{\sigma_1}, X_{\sigma_2},\ldots\in A\right\}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Looking at definition of exchangeable event from other references, it seems to me that $(2)$ is the "good" definition and not $(1)$.

---

---

---

Am I wrong? If so, why - in the spirit of Mörters/Peres definition - doesn't it hold true that:
\begin{equation}
\left\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\in A\right\}\supset\left\{X_{\sigma_1}, X_{\sigma_2},\ldots\in A\right\}
\end{equation}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those definitions are equivalent. Note that $\sigma^{-1}$ is also a finite permutation. If $A$ is an exchangeable event by the Mortërs/Peres definition, since we know $\{X_{\sigma_1}, X_{\sigma_2}, \dots \in A\} \in \mathcal{F}$ we can apply the definition using the finite permutation $\sigma^{-1}$ to obtain $\{X_1,X_2, \cdots \in A\} \supseteq \{X_{\sigma_1}, X_{\sigma_2}, \dots \in A\}$.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that they just focus on the "direction" $\subseteq$, but the other way round is true as well. And it is easily showable following your approach, by means of $\sigma^{-1}$. Correct?

Comment: Yes. Basically, if you exchange a finite numbers of rv',s you stay on $A$. If you reverse them back, you also stay in $A$.